# Is it possible to populate tables in my *.sdf database from a *.txt file?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, ado.net

So all is in my question. I have an web application in asp.net, with two databases :

The first `ASPNETDB.MDF` and the second `MyApp.sdf`

I would like to populate the tables of `MyApp.sdf` from an external file such as a txt file or something else.

Is this possible in Visual Studio 2010 ? Is there any way to do that ?

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a simple app:

```
    using (SqlConnection sqlcnn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=myapp.sdf"))
    {
        SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand();
        sqlcmd.Connection = sqlcnn;

        sqlcnn.Open();

        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"c:\mydir\myfile.txt");

        while (sr.Peek() != -1) // check for eof (end of file)
        {
            String line = sr.ReadLine();

            String[] values = line.Split(' '); // e.g if your values are seperated by space

            sqlcmd.CommandText = String.Format("INSERT INTO tableName VALUES ({0},{1},{2})", values[0], values[1], values[2]);

            sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, where I should write this code in my app ? In my HomeController ? In a distinct class ? And, one more thing...Can you briefly explain this line `(sr.Peek() != -1)`  mainly ` != -1 `  just to know

Comment: Updated answer, if you want to populate it once, create a simple winform app and execute the code upon a button click, but if you want to update your database each time a user visit your website then it should be in an action method in your controller

Comment: Ok, I just want populate it once. So I create a new project winform into my solution with this code, and it will work ? I'll try and come back here to say if it works. Thanks again

Comment: Sorry one more thing, where should be "myfile.txt" ? Or could I inform the all path into quotes like "c:\mydir\myfile.txt" ?

Comment: if your file is in the same directory of exe file then myfile.txt suffice, otherwise your should provide the full path

Answer (score 0):

You can also use bcp -the BULK INSERT command with a file including records separated by a field terminator. For example:

```
BULK INSERT tablename 
FROM 'c:\file.txt' 
WITH 
( 
    FIRSTROW = 2, // if the first row contains table field names
    MAXERRORS = 0, 
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ',', //separator character
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n' 
)
```

Comment: I'll ask the same thing as the previous answer, where I must write this query ? Directly in visual studio (right clic on my db, new query, etc...) or somewhere in my code app ?

Comment: @Alternative The nature of what you want to achieve is the question I think. If you want to do a maintenance kind of thing then you use SQL SERVER query console etc.. You can event create a script including the BULK INSERT statements and use task scheduler in Windows. Or if you/your users are gonna import a file containing the data generated/received in a text file then you should use the above application code. You may add this as a query in your app in Visual Studio, but I'm not sure.